# How to match all characters at once and exclude some of them

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match only strings and numbers, in the other hand, I want to exclude all other characters like `+` and `/`

Working example:

```
"text":"AQAAAXAiGIjaAAUwYjFmMWM0NDE3MTBhZDMzMzE3MDE1MDlmZmQ5OWRhOAAAJuDnir0XXwhG0sKLD+/eE/z4oAQ*"
```

this is the regex code that i have tried:

```
/"text":"(.*)"/i
```

but it match everything.

Comment: From the `nsregularexpression` description: **This tag should be used only for questions specific to the NSRegularExpression class.**

Comment: Disclaimer: I don't know Swift. If this is your whole text to match against, use something like `/[a-z]+|\d+/i` and ignore the first result, which will be `text`. If your example is just a part of a larger string, try `/"text":"|\G(?!\A)(?:([a-z]+|\d+)|[+\/]+)/i` and take your results only from capture group 1 of each match and ignore the matched strings. This regex syntax seems to be supported according to the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsregularexpression).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.` matches any character except newline. Use a character set to be more restrictive.

```
/"text":"([a-z\d]*)"/i
```

Comment: can you check it please? i tried it when it arrive to + it stops matching

Comment: You said you don't want to match them.

Comment: You can't skip over them. A regular expression always matches a contiguous string. You should match the whole thing and then remove the characters you don't want from the result.